# Managing Hibernate Session on Quartz Batch Process with Multiple Spring @Transactional Annotations

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, quartz-scheduler, spring-transactions

We are using Quartz to run a batch process that performs updates to our user's data and then sends an email based on specific state of the user's account.  But we can't seem to manage the hibernate session beyond a committed transaction and we get a Hibernate `LazyInitializationException` after we commit a transaction and attempt to access lazy objects in our data model.

How can we keep the hibernate session alive between multiple transactions so we can continue to access lazy objects?

What we want is something like the following flow of code:

- Quartz triggers our process.
- Open a new session with hibernate.
- Read all records needing update from the database.
- Start new transaction with `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)`
- Attempt to update our user's account state.
- Commit the transaction.
- If the user's account state changes send the user an email explaining the state change.  This is where the `LazyInitializationException` is thrown.
- Rinse, wash, repeat until all user records have been updated.

We want to follow something super similar to the Spring [`OpenSessionInViewFilter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate5/support/OpenSessionInViewFilter.html) model, but we aren't able to set up our code properly and our session always seems to get closed after the first `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)` commits.



**Questions**

How do we setup hibernate ourselves on new threads?

Which leads me into my second question:

Should we be using the Spring [`OpenSessionInViewInterceptor`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate5/support/OpenSessionInViewInterceptor.html) class for this work?  It seems like this is the behavior we want, but it doesn't quite feel right.

It looks like the [`SchedulerFactoryBean`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/quartz/SchedulerFactoryBean.html) has a method [`setTransactionManager(PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/quartz/SchedulerAccessor.html#setTransactionManager-org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager-), is that method just to store Quartz Triggers into a database or is it used to manage transactions when that particular Quartz task is running?



**Things We Tried**

Placing an `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)` at the beginning of our Quartz task, but the transaction wouldn't commit until all the records were updated.  So our user's were being sent emails stating that their account status has changed, they would check our site before the transaction would commit and see the old data of their account and be confused because they were seeing old information, and therefore it was clear that "...the developers have lost control of the system and don't know what they are doing."

Very embarrassing to say the least.

Comment: Umm... why not initialize all the data required for the email *while still within the transaction*?

Comment: We could.  But now, that transaction, that particular piece of work, has to know more about the application than just what is suppose to happen in the transaction.  It feels as though there is coupling between to parts of the application and a breaking of the Single Responsibility Principle.

Comment: How so? Isn't the transactional code already capable of accessing the lazily fetched associations? In other words, apparently the fact that transactional code *doesn't currently touch* certain entity fields is enough guarantee that SRP isn't broken, so what does it matter if those fields are initialized or not?

Comment: @crizzis I appreciate your comments and your desire to help work around the problem, but having code in the transaction that isn't specific to what needs to occur in that transaction isn't acceptable to me.